# What is the best way to create ground truth annotations for object detection?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently playing with a recently released implementations of SSD and other object detection in tensorflow.

I was able to train pet detector and now would like to create my own dataset and train on this.

So the question is: 

- what is the best way to create ground truth annotations (bbox/type) for the images? 

- what tools to use to create bbox/type annotations? 

- what scripts to use to convert annotations to TFRecords format?

- is there a tool, that enables to create annotations in the form suitable for existing conversion scripts, that comes with tensorflow (pets, voc)?

Thanks,
- Alexey

Answer (score 1):

This [Github project](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) will do exactly what you want: it allows hand annotation for ground truth, and puts it in `xml` format specified by PASCAL VOC and ImageNet. You can then easily convert `xml` to `TFRecord` by modifying this [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) provided by the Tensorflow team.

Also, check out the [labelme](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme) library.

MATLAB also has a ground truth labeling tool, but you have to write some code to convert it into `xml` format. Check out this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/trainingimagelabeler-app.html).